# Decode URL Inside HTTP Redirect

Tags: http, url, redirect, decode, encode

Here's my code:

```
<script>
  jQuery(window).attr("location", "https://myurl.com?firstname=Bretest&lastname=Martest&email=test1%40test.com&phone=(987) 654-3210");
</script>
```

Problem is, the url that I get redirected to is encoded:

https://myurl.com?firstname=Bretest&amp%3Blastname=Martest&amp%3Bemail=test1%40test.com&amp%3Bphone=%28987%29+654-3210

How can I get the "&" to come through decoded?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use :

```
window.location.href = "your address";
```